# Struggling to create Extension with plpython3u in postgresql 16.1

Tags: postgresql

When I run in Postgresql 16.1:
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u

I get:
ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found.

I checked that the file does exist (C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/lib/plpython3.dll)

I don't know what python version I should use, so I installed 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 and 3.12 and specified them all in the environment variables.

I copied the python310.dll to system32 but I still get the same error.

I downloaded the installer certified by CBD for Windows on my local machine from https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

This file appeared automatically C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/lib/plpython3.dll

I then tried to run CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u in pgadmin as a query which resulted in the error mentioned.

I have owner permission of the file.

Comment: 1) How did you install Postgres? 2) How did you install the plpythonu3 extension to the OS? 3) Does the server user have permissions on the file and the directories above it? **Add answers as text update to the question text**.